# Error: Too many re-renders in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to update the loading state to `false` after fetching data from database. Is there anything I am missing?

The error occurred in the `setLoading` function inside `useEffect`.

```
    const SingleProduct = ({ productName }) => {
      const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    
      // The line of code helps to convert hyphenated text to a spaced out text for database reading.
      const convertedProductName = convertToDefaultProductName(productName);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const getProduct = async () => {
          try {
            const result = await publicRequest.get(
              `products/find/${convertedProductName}`
            );
    
            setProduct(result.data);
            setLoading(false); // BIG BUG IN THIS LINE.
          } catch (err) {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        };
    
        getProduct();
      }, [productName]);
    
      console.log(product, loading);
      const reOrderedProduct = sortSimilarProduct(product);
    
      return (
        <Container loading={loading}>
          {loading ? (
            <CircularProgress size="8rem" />
          ) : (
            <SingleProductDetails
              productName={convertedProductName}
              productDetails={reOrderedProduct}
            />
          )}
        </Container>
      );
    };
```

Here is the parent component of the `SingleProduct` Component

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import PageTitle from '../components/PageTitle/PageTitle';
import SingleProduct from '../components/SingleProduct/SingleProduct';
import Footer from '../components/Footer/Footer';
import Announcement from "../components/Announcement/Announcement";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { splitAndSpace } from '../usefulFunc';


const Product = () => {
    const { productName } = useParams();
    
    return(
        <>
            <Announcement /> 
            <Navbar />
            <PageTitle title={splitAndSpace(productName, "-")} pageLocation={"Home | Shop | ... | " + productName} params={productName}/>
            <SingleProduct productName={productName}/>
            <Footer borderTop/>
        </>
    );
};

export default Product;
```

Comment: Why have you initialised `loading` to `true`? It should be `false` to start with. Only when you do your fetch set it to `true`, and then when the fetch is complete set it back to `false`. Also, why are you passing `loading` into the Container as a prop?

Comment: May I know what is `productName` in your useEffect dependency args, where did you get that from?

Comment: ```const SingleProduct = ({productName}) => {```

Comment: @Andy I wanted my application to load initially before the data is fetched.

Comment: Can you paste the complete code for the `SingleProduct` component here, it would add more clarity to the question.

Comment: You can put something like ` if (!loading) return;` at the start of your useEffect callback but I don't see anything in your code that would cause an infinite state/render loop.

Comment: @Chris G, still not working.

Comment: What I would try to do is to validate every step of your assumptions. i.e. logging the exact control flow this component will go through, by adding logs to the useEffect and main body of the component function. The things that can cause a re-render are a change in the component's state, or in its props, so figure out which of those are triggering the change that then leads to the beginning of the infinite loop.

Comment: @MichaelFlores, I have tried every possible solution to try and resolve this bug. I have used these lines of code for loading in other components as well. They haven't reported any bug.